# excel formula with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, multiple-conditions

I can do a very long If type formula... but there must be something easier.  So I just need the "Amnt" result in "1", the parameters are

Thanks and hope this makes sense.

if terms are more than 10, and Days past are greater than 30, Amnt,"0"
if terms are between 11 and 29, and Days Past are greater than 60,Amnt,"0"
if terms are greater than 30, and Days Past are less than 90, Amnt,"0"

So resulting in either the "Amnt" or blank/0 in column "1"...  then I would just use a formula in "2"..  If("1">0, 0/ "", "Amnt"

Terms   Days Past   Amnt      "1"            "2"

5   25          100   100
5   35          100                      100
12  58          100   100
12  62          100                      100
32  72          100   100
32  92          100                  100

Comment: the spaces were eliminated... the columns are "terms" "days Past" "Amnt" "1" "2".... so the first two are the relevant columns ... then assume any dollar value, and a result .

Comment: actually lost all formatting to my question...I could not get past the website filters, so I had to take out anything formula looking... now it doesn't make sense.  1st time on this site.... not loving it.

Comment: Can you copy-paste a screenshot instead also with the expecting results?  But based on what I understand, `IF` is probably the only way to go unless you want to create a macro.